# "Antizener" device

Tags: diodes, zener, over-voltage-protection

A Zener diode normally starts conducting current when the voltage applied across its terminals rises over a certain threshold, called the Zener voltage.
After this threshold the current keeps increasing.

Is there an electronic device / component which stops conducting current if the voltage goes above over a certain voltage?
Or a circuit (simple as a Zener diode) with this function?
I know that will  be unlikely to conduct an infinite current at zero voltage.

Comment: Specifically voltage? Not a single discrete device. Well, there is a JFET or other depletion mode device but those are 3 terminal.

Comment: How can this work? If the device is conducting, then the voltage on it is ~zero, so how can it go higher?

Comment: With two (or more) devices sure. One single? An PTC behaves slightly in the way you describe, low ohmic at low voltage and higher (but in no way fully off) at high voltage.

Comment: MOV? TVS? Crowbar? Active clamps? PTC? Fuse? Active current limiter or CC source.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 OP wants the opposite: Detects high voltage and opens the circuit.

Comment: perhaps a fuse? although not quite, that's current operated. Something like a polyswitch ? (actually, if you don't mind it operating a bit slowly, and only once - a resistor ...)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Certainly not. A resistor conducts down to infinitely low voltage and the voltage across it can certainly go higher.

Comment: Some say Zenner but I say Zeener however it is spelt Zener

Comment: This older case has some easy to build circuits you maybe could use: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/435418/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-negative-resistance At least one of them does something which resembles what you described.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was intending to show other means of interrupting Zener current with a bypass clamp

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Oh, I see.

Comment: @winny I presume the OP is interested in a device with very low dynamic resistance similar to Zener diode

Comment: A Gunn diode won't become an open circuit, but its current drops when voltage exceeds a threshold.

Comment: Poor specs. Define voltage, current,  risetime , duration and reaction time to stop current and voltage , surge rating of Zener. There exists a SOA, but you need to define what needs to be protected more than just “a voltage threshold”

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well aware. I was just pointing out that conducing and voltage go higher are not mutually exclusive as you asked it.

Comment: Specs: Voltage 5V (the threshold ), current : miliampers (<10 mA), Risetime, duration, reaction : not important (lets say for 50Hz)

Comment: Related but not necessarily what you want: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/452533/17387

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard to design a circuit that opens up (to some finite voltage) if the input exceeds some limit and "passes through" lower voltages, but such a circuit will not be as simple as a single device or two unless someone has already integrated it onto a chip.

I'm assuming it would essentially require three terminals (one to sense the voltage and two more for current in and out) rather than two terminals like the Zener ('Zeenah' if you want the more Germanic pronunciation, though Zener was born in the US) diode.

Note that such diodes above around 5-6V depend primarily on the avalanche effect, not the Zener effect (and it was not discovered by Clarence Melvin Avalanche).

Answer (score 0):

Such an "AntiZener diode" (circuit) can be made by two elements in series -  an *opposing diode* and *opposing voltage source*.

The name of this circuit is "diode limiter".

Answer (score -1):

> “I know that will be unlikely to conduct an infinite current at zero voltage”

But a crowbar after a fuse will conduct all the current at any voltage. (Limited by loop resistance)

Please be more specify on what protection is needed and why.